# 403 Forbidden clean apache2 install

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu and then installed the `lamp-server` bundle via `tasksel` and the installation went fine.

I had backed up the files from the `/var/www/` folder and planned to just place them back once the server was back online (or in my case, accesible from my computer only - it's a test server.)

The installation completed and so I tried to copy the files over from the backup directory. This went fine.

However, when I try to access the server via `localhost` from Firefox I get a 403 Forbidden error, which I never had before. HELP!!

**EDIT: 9/2/2013**  Added info about file happenings

So, I followed what @Andrew said, but I still can't access any .html files. Strangely enough, I can access the .php files (nothing displayed of course, as they only display the info pulled from a previously completed form.) But no html access, just the

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

page

Comment: Why did this work? It just worked for me.. can someone explain? I am a real hit and miss guy at this stuff, copying and pasting whatever I can... I know, I'm a nightmare.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, found the answer to my problem, albeit trying to help another user with a similar problem!

This question https://askubuntu.com/questions/343172/add-apache2-vhost-at-home gave a link that gave me a solution! I just had to run `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www` and now I can access it fine! Thanks for the help @Andrew, but I got this one myself!

Comment: Ahhh... that feeling when things start going your way... +1

Answer (score 1):

First, add your user to the `www-data` group.

> sudo adduser [ your username ] www-data

Then, set ownership of `/var/www/` to the `www-data` group.

> sudo chown [ your username ]:www-data /var/www

Finally, set permissions for the `/var/www/` directory.

> sudo chmod 777 /var/www
>
> sudo chmod g+s /var/www

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this out! Hopefully it fixes my problem!

Comment: Well, doing that gave me/www-data the ownership of /var/www, but...not the files inside. SO...I still can't access the server.

Comment: Apparently I can access the .php files (nothing comes up of course), but not the .html files?

Comment: @RPi_Awesomeness Try putting `-R` just after the `chown`, separated by spaces from everything else. I don't know if that'll work -- I don't have an Ubuntu reference on me, but it's common for commands to accept the `-R` flag to recursively operate on every file and subdirectory within them.

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!